# dup does not redirect

Tags: c++, linux, dup

I am writing code to redirect stdout to a file(such as the result of an ls being returned to a file) and the dup2() function does not redirect my output.  Here is the code that I have:

```
void testDup()
{
    int newft;
    if(newfd = creat("fout.txt", O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY) == -1)
    {
        cout << "Open failed"<< endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    dup2(newfd, 1);
    cout << "this should be in the new file" < endl;
}
```

And this does not work.  I just get the output of ls to my terminal window.  I have taken steps to check that dup2() did indeed return 1, and not -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a pair of parenthesis around the assignment, otherwise it's an assignment to a boolean expression (which returns 0 if the file could indeed be opened):

```
if ((newfd = creat("fout.txt", O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY)) == -1)
```